# Calculating power sums using integration/derivation part by part

Tags: calculus, summation

In Calculus, it is quite a necessity calculating the sum of a power sum of the concept: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {c_n x^n} $$

Can somebody explain how does one calculate the value of a sum using other known sums and integration/derivation part by part?
Take for example:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(n^2 + n +2) x^n} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometric series is
$$
\sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^{\infty} {x^n}=\dfrac1{1-x}, \ \forall |x|<1. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$
Let's find first the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$.
We differentiate both sides of (1) with respect to $x$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n-1}}=\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}, \ \forall |x|<1 .
$$
Now if we multiply both sides of the last one with $x$, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {nx^{n}}=\dfrac{x}{(1-x)^2}, \ \forall |x|<1. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2) 
$$
Differentiate another time to find the
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {n^2x^{n}}. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3) 
$$

Combine (1), (2) and (3) to find $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(n^2 + n +2) x^n} .$$

Comment: I couldn't get to (3).
Can you help?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Where did you stuck?

Comment: I just did (2)^2  but apparently that does not work.

Comment: Which gave me: $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} { n^2 x^n} = (\frac{1-x^2-(1-x^2)^2}{(1-x^2)^2(1-x^2)})^2 $

Comment: @TheNotMe: That is wrong. Did you understand how I got (2) from (1)? I differentiate with respect to $x$. Try to understand that first and then proceed to (3).

Comment: $nx^{n-1} - x^n = nx^n$ that's why, that I understand... Can you please show me the full solution? I still do not have a clue...

Comment: I still can't calculate $\sum n^2 x^n$

Comment: Still not working! :/

Comment: @TheNotMe: I change the solution for (2). Now do you understand how I got (2) from (1)? Can you apply the same to (2) to find (3)?

Comment: thank you.
I got that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n^2 x^n} = {x\cdot [\frac{x^2 +1}{(1-x)^4} ]    }$

Comment: @TheNotMe: I think is $x\cdot\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x)^4}$. Am I right?

Comment: You basically got what I got, yes!

Comment: @TheNotMe: Be careful in (1) because the summation there starts from 0 while in your exercise the summation start from 1.

Comment: so I just subtract 1

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes!

Comment: Idk why the final sum was a tiny bit different than Wolfram, but thank you for ALL your help, truly!

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$
z \frac{d}{dz} \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} n c_n z^n
$$
If you define the operator $z D = z \dfrac{d}{dz}$, you see that:
$$
(z D)^m \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} n^m c_n z^n
$$
If now $p(x)$ is a polynomial:
$$
p(z D) \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n z^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} p(n) c_n z^n
$$